# Show that a measure is a probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I have trouble with this question:

We define an arc segment $B(\theta, \eta, r, R)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\vert \omega(x)\in [\theta,\eta], \Vert x \Vert_2 \in [r,R] \}$ where $0 \leq \theta \leq \eta < 2 \pi$ og $ R \geq r>0$ and $\theta, \eta$. In fact the arc segment is the vectors with lenght between r and R and form an angle with the first axis between $\theta$ and $\eta$.

We define:
$\omega: \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb{R} $ with $\omega(x)\in [0,2π)$ which is uniquely determined by

$ \frac{x_1}{\Vert x \Vert_2}=\cos(\omega)$ and $ \frac{x_2}{\Vert x \Vert_2}=\sin(\omega)$

$\omega$ is continous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash\{(x_1,0)\vert x_1 \geq 0\}$

We let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}_2) $ satisfying that $\mu(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)=0$ and $\mu(B(\theta, \eta, r, R))=\frac{\eta-\theta}{2 \pi}\int_r^Rue^{-u^2/2}du$

Now I have to show that a measure satisfying these two conditions is a probability measure.

I think I have to show that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^2)=1$, but how do i do that?

Comment: You want to compute $\mu(\mathbb R^2)$, so first write $\mathbb R^2=\bigcup_nB(0,\eta_n,0,R_n)$ for an increasing sequence of sets $B(0,\eta_n,0,R_n)$ (Can you do this?). Then, write $\mu(\mathbb R^2)=\lim_n\mu(B(0,\eta_n,0,R_n))$ and compute the limit. (By the way there is a mistake in your definition of $\mu$, the integration should be between $r$ and $R$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can't see how $B(0,η_n,0,Rn)$ is satisfying the conditions for an arc segment, because we required r>0, but here we have r=0?

Comment: And do we still have that $\eta_n<2π$ for all n in the expression $B(0,η_n,0,R_n)$? @Ian

Comment: Oh sorry I failed to notice the requirement that $r>0$. In that case, just choose $B(0,\eta_n,r_n,R_n)$ for sequences such that $\eta_n<2\pi$ and $r_n>0$ for all integers $n$. Do you see how to choose these sequences so that $\mathbb R^2=\bigcup_nB(0,\eta_n,r_n,R_n)$?

Comment: Thank you! Is this why it is important that $\mu(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)=0$ or where do we use this requirement?

Comment: In fact now that $r_n>0$, you can only construct sequences such that $\mathbb R^2=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_nB(0,\eta_n,r_n,R_n)$, so $\mu(\mathbb R^2)=\mu(\{0\})+\lim_n\mu(B(0,\eta_n,r_n,R_n))=\lim_n\mu(B(0,\eta_n,r_n,R_n))$, and this is where you use the requirement that $\mu(\{0\})=0$.

Comment: I makes sense, thank you a lot!